# JSF 2 - construct a page from two files - main and current content

Tags: java, jsf-2

I'm quite new to using JSF and I'm not sure if that's the right way to go, but in Rails you usually have a main application file into which the current page is loaded. That way I don't have to worry about copy-pasting the menu, etc. every time.

How can I achieve that with JSF 2? Can I navigate to the same main page every time and tell it to load a current content? Or do I tell the current page that I navigate to to load the "main frame around the content"?

Thanks!

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-templating-with-facelets-example/

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792862/how-to-include-another-xhtml-in-xhtml-using-jsf-2-0-facelets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes of course, JSF 2.0 has [page-templating feature](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jsf2fu2/index.html). You define a template that defines a generic layout to all the view pages.

Facelets tags to create basic page:

- **ui:insert** – defines content that is going to replace by the file that load the template;
- **ui:define** – defines content that is inserted into tag `ui:insert`;
- **ui:include** – includes content from another page;
- **ui:composition** – the specified template is loaded, if used with template attribute, and the children of this tag defines the template layout. In other case, it’s a group of elements, that can be inserted somewhere.

For example:

```
<ui:composition
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
     xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    template="/templates/myLayout.xhtml">

   <ui:define name="menu">
      <ui:include src="/mypath/menu.xhtml"/>
   </ui:define>

   <ui:define name="content"> 
     <ui:include src="/mypath/content.xhtml"/>           
   </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

or

```
<ui:insert name="content">
   <ui:include src="/mypath/mycontent.xhtml"/>
</ui:insert>
```

Answer (score 1):

JSF doesn't support what you want to archive. Instead, it support the views and basic layout(template). What you need it this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
template="path/to/template.xhtml>

<your custom content here/>
<ui:composition/>
```